# How can I add a <ViewCell> with a <Grid> to a TableView in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm constructing a dynamic TableView. So far I have this:

```
var section = new TableSection("Available Categories");
foreach (var category in categoryGroups)
{
   var name = (string)category.Name;
   var cell = new TextCell { Text = name };
   section.Add(cell);
}
tableView.Root.Add(section);
```

This works but instead of using a TextCell I would like to use a ViewCell with a grid same as I currently have in XAML:

```
< ViewCell >
   < Grid VerticalOptions = "CenterAndExpand" Padding = "20, 0" >
      < Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
         < ColumnDefinition Width = "*" />
         < ColumnDefinition Width = "Auto" />
         < ColumnDefinition Width = "20" />
      </ Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
      < Label Style = "{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" Grid.Column = "0" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand" Text = "{Binding Name}" />
      < Label Style = "{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" Grid.Column = "1" HorizontalOptions = "End" XAlign = "End" Text = "{Binding TotalWordCount}" VerticalOptions = "Center" TextColor = "Gray" />
      < Label Grid.Column = "2" Text = "{x:Static local:FontAwesome.FACheck}" HorizontalTextAlignment = "End" HorizontalOptions = "End" FontFamily = "FontAwesome" XAlign = "Center" FontSize = "13" IsVisible = "{Binding IsToggled}" TextColor = "#1E90FF" />
   </ Grid >
</ ViewCell >
```

Can anyone give me advice on how I can add this to my C# code. I know how to do it in XAML only.

Note

Here is where I learned about Dynamic Styles:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/device/

Comment: 'what exactly this means "ListView.Header look like the header areas on the settings pages"? do you need just to change the color or something else? have you tried to change the color of stack layout?

Comment: Hi Yuri,  I would just like to be able to customize this with an iOS renderer if possible.  Would like to change the header also rather than add a new stackLayout inside of it.

Comment: If other answers are not enough please let me know or even better look here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/listview/ This renderer is not simple and I would try to avoid it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Option 1: Define custom ViewCell in C#

This is what C# equivalent of the XAML template you shared would look like:

```
public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public CustomViewCell()
    {
        var label1 = new Label
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
        };

        //or, label1.Style = Device.Styles.ListItemTextStyle;
        label1.SetDynamicResource(VisualElement.StyleProperty, "ListItemTextStyle");
        Grid.SetColumn(label1, 0);
        label1.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

        var label2 = new Label
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            //XAlign = TextAlignment.End, //not needed
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            TextColor = Color.Gray
        };

        //or, label2.Style = Device.Styles.ListItemTextStyle;
        label2.SetDynamicResource(VisualElement.StyleProperty, "ListItemTextStyle");
        Grid.SetColumn(label2, 1);
        label2.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "TotalWordCount");

        var label3 = new Label
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            //XAlign = TextAlignment.Start, //not needed
            FontFamily = "FontAwesome",
            FontSize = 13,
            TextColor = Color.FromHex("#1E90FF"),
            Text = FontAwesome.FACheck,
        };
        Grid.SetColumn(label3, 2);
        label3.SetBinding(VisualElement.IsVisibleProperty, "IsToggled");

        var grid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Padding = new Thickness(20, 0),
            ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
            {
                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(20) },
            },
            Children = {
                label1,
                label2,
                label3
            }
        };

        View = grid;
    }
}
```

---

### Option 2: Define custom ViewCell in XAML

Even if you are dynamically creating your `TableView` you can still use the XAML based approach. Just create a new XAML control as following:

**Sample ViewCell XAML**

```
<ViewCell 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="AppNamespace.MyViewCell">
    <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding = "20, 0" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column = "0" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand" Text = "{Binding Name}" />
        <Label Grid.Column = "1" HorizontalOptions = "End" XAlign = "End" Text = "{Binding TotalWordCount}" VerticalOptions = "Center" TextColor = "Gray" />
        <Switch Grid.Column = "2" HorizontalOptions = "End"  IsToggled = "{Binding IsToggled}"  />
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public partial class MyViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public MyViewCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and you can create your `TableView` as following:

```
var section = new TableSection("Available Categories");
foreach (var category in categoryGroups)
{
   var cell = new MyViewCell { BindingContext = category };
   section.Add(cell);
}
tableView.Root.Add(section);
```

---

### Option 3. Create your own custom `TableView` with `ItemSource` support like `ListView`

```
public class DynamicTableView : TableView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Bindable property for the data source
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        "ItemsSource", typeof(IDictionary), typeof(DynamicTableView), propertyChanging: OnItemsSourceChanged);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the items source - can be any collection of elements.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The items source.</value>
    public IDictionary ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IDictionary)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bindable property for the data template to visually represent each item.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        "ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(DynamicTableView));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the item template used to generate the visuals for a single item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The item template.</value>
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes an ItemsControl.
    /// </summary>
    public DynamicTableView()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the underlying data source is changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bindable">ItemsSource</param>
    /// <param name="oldValue">Old value.</param>
    /// <param name="newValue">New value.</param>
    static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((DynamicTableView)bindable).OnItemsSourceChangedImpl((IDictionary)oldValue, (IDictionary)newValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instance method called when the underlying data source is changed through the
    /// <see cref="ItemsSource"/> property. This re-generates the list based on the 
    /// new collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oldValue">Old value.</param>
    /// <param name="newValue">New value.</param>
    void OnItemsSourceChangedImpl(IDictionary oldValue, IDictionary newValue)
    {
        Root.Clear();
        if(newValue != null)
        {
            FillContainer(newValue);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method takes our items source and generates visuals for
    /// each item in the collection; it can reuse visuals which were created
    /// previously and simply changes the binding context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newValue">New items to display</param>
    void FillContainer(IDictionary newValue)
    {
        Root.Clear();

        var template = ItemTemplate;

        foreach(var key in newValue.Keys)
        {
            var tableSection = new TableSection() { Title = key.ToString() };
            var innerList = newValue[key] as IList;
            if (innerList == null)
                innerList = Enumerable.Repeat(newValue[key], 1).ToList();

            foreach(var dataItem in innerList)
            {
                if (template != null)
                {
                    var view = InflateTemplate(template, dataItem);
                    if (view != null)
                        tableSection.Add(view);
                }
                else
                {
                    var label = new TextCell { Text = dataItem.ToString() };
                    tableSection.Add(label);
                }
            }

            Root.Add(tableSection);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inflates the visuals for a data template or template selector
    /// and adds it to our StackLayout.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="template">Template.</param>
    /// <param name="item">Item.</param>
    ViewCell InflateTemplate(DataTemplate template, object item)
    {
        // Pull real template from selector if necessary.
        var dSelector = template as DataTemplateSelector;
        if (dSelector != null)
            template = dSelector.SelectTemplate(item, this);

        var view = template.CreateContent() as ViewCell;
        if (view != null)
        {
            view.BindingContext = item;
            return view;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and usage will look like:

```
<local:DynamicTableView ItemsSource="{Binding AllCategories}">
    <local:DynamicTableView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding = "20, 0" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column = "0" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand" Text = "{Binding Name}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column = "1" HorizontalOptions = "End" XAlign = "End" Text = "{Binding TotalWordCount}" VerticalOptions = "Center" TextColor = "Gray" />
                    <Switch Grid.Column = "2" HorizontalOptions = "End"  IsToggled = "{Binding IsToggled}"  />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:DynamicTableView.ItemTemplate>
</local:DynamicTableView>
```

and sample data-set:

```
public class SettingsViewModel {
    public Categories AllCategories => new Categories();
}

public class Category {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TotalWordCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsToggled { get; set; }
}
public class Categories : Dictionary<string, List<Category>>
{
    public Categories()
    {
        this.Add("Available Categories", new List<Category>(new []{
            new Category(){ Name = "Test1", TotalWordCount = 10, IsToggled = true },
            new Category(){ Name = "Test2", TotalWordCount = 25, IsToggled = true },
            new Category(){ Name = "Test3", TotalWordCount = 20, IsToggled = false }
        }));

        this.Add("Other Categories", new List<Category>(new[]{
            new Category(){ Name = "Test-N1", TotalWordCount = 30, IsToggled = true },
            new Category(){ Name = "Test-N2", TotalWordCount = 50, IsToggled = false }
        }));
    }
}
```

---

**Older answer based on older question (no longer valid)**

If you just need to specify `BackgroundColor` or `FontSize` for a particular platform - you can do that by using `OnPlatform` - you shouldn't need a custom renderer.

```
<ListView.Header>
    <!-- don't forget to override spacing and padding properties to avoid default spacing -->
   <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color"
             Android=""
             WinPhone=""                                         
             iOS="#000000">
      </StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
      <StackLayout Padding="10,35,10,10" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <local:ExtLabel ExtStyleId="Body" Text="Custom body Label"></local:ExtLabel>
         <local:ExtLabel ExtStyleId="Header" Text="Custom hdr Label"></local:ExtLabel>
      </StackLayout>
   </StackLayout>
</ListView.Header>
```

Also, on referencing the source code for [listview](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ListView.cs) and [renderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs), and [specifically here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs#L468) - it looks like the header/header-template property just functions as a placeholder for a set of controls in `ListView`. If you supply a custom-control in header, the framework will instantiate and use the renderer for it.

So if you really need a custom-renderer based approach, then you can then create a custom control, (for e.g. `CustomListViewHeader`); and implement a iOS renderer for it.

You can then use this control in your `ListView` header or header-template.

```
<ListView.Header>
   <local:CustomListViewHeader />
</ListView.Header>
```

Comment: Option 3. is a good choice for MVVM but on run-time wont work. When on run-time I add a row to the table, it doesn't add the row. Whats the solution?

Comment: I add a row to the AllCategories list int the binded class to the table's page. So how can I say to the table that the ItemSorce has changed?

Comment: You will have to modify `OnItemsSourceChangedImpl` to check if collection supports INotifyCollectionChanged and subscribe to it's event. And you can use an Observable collection as items source.